# How can I monitor Neural Engine usage on Apple Silicon M1?

Tags: activity-monitor, apple-silicon

I'm now successfully training my TensorFlow (2.5.0-rc1) models in my new Macbook Air M1 (yay!). But, for performance optimization and out of sheer curiosity, I'd like to monitor usage and performance of the 16 Neural Engine cores, as TensorFlow should be using them profusely.

Unfortunately I can't find any way to monitor the Neural Engine. The **Activity Monitor** only includes `% CPU` and `% GPU` indicators, including history graphs for both, but I don't see any Neural Engine indicators. The GPU sits at 0% for TensorFlow runs, so usage is not being consolidated there, which makes sense. So probably it's being shown as part of CPU usage, which sits at ~300% during the training session, but I can't really tell.

I tried peeking into the Mach `/include` folders looking for any relevant headers, and the closest I got was in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/usr/include/mach/task_info.h` (on my machine), where I've only found data members for things such as `ledger_tag_neural_footprint` (seems  related to memory usage) and `task_gpu_utilisation` but no neural task/process/vm usage.

I wonder if it's an omission on their part, or maybe it's in the roadmap, or it's just not possible to get that from this hardware (I doubt it!).

Comment: What does monitor look like to you? When you run a training job, doesn’t it log the start time and end time?

Comment: It's strange to me that your GPU% is zero. I have a similar setup and the GPU History graph shows 100% utilization during training. Are you using the tensorflow-metal package?